# How can I specify a binding context in Vue.js just like in knockout.js and WPF

Tags: javascript, binding, vue.js, binding-context

We are using [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/), very nice framework if you ask me. From [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) and [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx) I know that a context can be specified for the bindings. How can this be done with Vue.js?

See the example below. Here `binding-context` is pseudo code for the functionality I am looking for in Vue.

```
Vue.component('hosting-setup', {
template:
    '<wizard>' +
        '<wizard-step binding-context="step1" :title="title">' +
            '<select :options="choices"></select>' +
        '</wizard-step>' +
        '<wizard-step binding-context="step2" :title="title">' +
            '<select :options="choices"></select>' +
        '</wizard-step>' +
    '</wizard>',

    data: function () {
        return {
            step1: {
                title: 'Choose virtualization software',
                choices: ['Virtual Box', 'VMWare'],
                choice: undefined,
            },
            step2: {
                title: 'Choose guest operating system',
                choices: ['Debian 6', 'Ubuntu 16', 'Windows Server 2012'],
                choice: undefined
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no "with" binding equivalent in `Vue`. There are a few approaches for what you want to do, but for your example I would use a `computed` to return your data as an array and then use `v-for` to print out each component passing the relevant data as a prop:

**Vue Instance**

```
Vue.component('wizard-step', {
  template: `<div>{{title}}</div>`,
  props: ['title']
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    wizardSteps() {
      return [this.step1, this.Step2]
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      step1: {
        title: 'Choose virtualization software',
        choices: ['Virtual Box', 'VMWare'],
        choice: undefined,
      },
      Step2: {
        title: 'Choose guest operating system',
        choices: ['Debian 6', 'Ubuntu 16', 'Windows Server 2012'],
        choice: undefined
      }
    };
  }
})
```

**Markup**

```
  <wizard-step :title="step.title" v-for="(step, index) in wizardSteps" :key="index"></wizard-step>
```

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/craig_h_411/vzq25go5/

**EDIT**

If you want to pass the data down to the component directly, you can use `v-bind` to pass the object and declare the object property names you want to use in the component as `props`, which maybe gets closer to what you are asking for, so:

```
Vue.component('wizard-step', {
  template: `<div>
    {{title}}
    <select>
      <option v-for="choice in choices" >{{choice}}</option> 
    </select>
  </div>`,
  props: ['title','choices']
});
```

**Parent markup**

```
  <wizard-step v-bind="step1"></wizard-step>
  <wizard-step v-bind="Step2"></wizard-step>
```

Here's the JSFiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/craig_h_411/7dg41j0w/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The given code example is actually completely made up for the purpose of this question. The given v-for does not seem to be applicable in our case.

Comment: +1 because I wasn't aware of the v-bind. It doesn't however feels completely satisfactory because creating components solely for the purpose of not having to specify the full data property path seems kind of cumbersome. I could apply v-bind in some code I have written some time earlier though, where I created components for the sake of separation of concerns anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you have really nested child, can try to cheat using v-for with 1 item array.

```
<template v-for="local in [data.nest1.nest2.nest3]">
    //normal binding using local.XXXX
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Vue 2.6.10:

```
<template>
    <wizard>
        <wizard-step v-if="props.step1 ? step = props.step1 : false" :title="step.title">
            <select :options="step.choices"></select>
        </wizard-step>
        <wizard-step v-if="props.step2 ? step = props.step2 : false" :title="step.title">
            <select :options="step.choices"></select>
        </wizard-step> 
    </wizard>
</template>
```

NOTE: Even better, for more concise code you could create a sub-component just for  and pass title and options:

I.e.

```
<template>
    <wizard>
        <wizard-step v-if="props.step1" :step="props.step1" />
        <wizard-step v-if="props.step2" :step="props.step2" />
    </wizard>
</template>
```

and your child wizard-step will be:

```
<template>
    <wizard-step :title="step.title">
        <select :options="step.choices"></select>
    </wizard-step>
</template>
```

And another improvement, if you are in control on how the data returned is structured, you could return an array of `steps` (instead of step1 and step2), and you could just simplify further with a for-each:

```
<template>
    <wizard>
        <wizard-step v-for="step in props.data" :step="step" />
    </wizard>
</template>
```